# Or filter in F3

Tags: php, mongodb, fat-free-framework

To filter my documents in MongoDB I use this: `$filter = array('title' => $regex ? $regex : new \MongoRegex('/.*/i'));`

I am also using the Pagination plugin if that matters.

I need to be able to filter to the title ***or*** description. Something like this: $filter = `array('title' => $regex ? $regex : new \MongoRegex('/.*/i')` **OR** `'description' => $regex ? $regex : new \MongoRegex('/.*/i'));`

Any help on this would be much appreciated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's something like that (but untested):

```
array(
 "$or"=> [
   "title": $regex ? $regex : new \MongoRegex('/.*/i'),
   "description": $regex ? $regex : new \MongoRegex('/.*/i')
 ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out myself just now, gonna put my answer in a sec.

BTW: F3 is cool man! Thanks for that.